# sftp upload bash ignore files

Tags: linux, bash, git, sftp

I try to achieve some semi-automatic `sftp` upload/deployment. The main key is **NOT** to upload all files. I do not know which files to upload but I know which files not to upload.

My bash script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP="123.123.123.123"
HOSTNAME="ftp.my-host.com"
PATH="subdirectory"

sftp username@$HOSTNAME:$PATH < "sftp-pattern"
```

in the `sftp-pattern` file i want to store my sftp commands. But I could not find any hints how to ignore several patterns. like `*.sql`.

Ideally i'd ignore everything that is gitignored.

I do **NOT** have an ssh connection.

Comment: You might find [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) helpful. It can be used like `git ftp push` and then pushes the current `HEAD` to the ftp remote. I'm not sure about SFTP.

Comment: sounds awesome!! thanks!

Comment: Btw.: `PATH` is an important environment variable.

Comment: thanks for that hint @Cyrus!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer should be [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) as  @Clijsters mentioned. It is more feature rich and needs no fiddeling around with loops and pipes.

dwrights solution is working though, if it is *ONLY* sql that you want to exclude.

Thanks!!

Comment: BTW: in the end i solved it with **gitium**, since the use-case is a wordpress page. gitium seems actively maintained and has the support i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a shell script, you could use a loop. Something like this should work.

```
#!/bin/bash

IP="123.123.123.123"
HOST="ftp.my-host.com"
DIR="/tmp/"

for f in `/bin/ls $DIR`
do
  if echo $f | /usr/bin/grep  '.sql' > /dev/null
  then
    echo SKIPPING $f
  else
   sftp username@$HOST:$DIR/$f
  fi
done
```